# Is it possible to inject a script to click on the confirm button in metamask?

Tags: metamask

I am trying to write an extension that can interact with the contract. Upon interaction with the contract, i want to use the script to click confirm the transaction on Metamask.

[metamask pop up requiring confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOI68.png)

I am unable to inject a script and i have tried for days.

```
 chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.title == "MetaMask Notification" && tab.status == "complete") {
        console.log(tab.url);
        let regex = new RegExp('chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/notification\.html#confirm-transaction/[0-9]+/token-method');
        if (regex.test(tab.url)) {
            console.log('yes we got the correct url');
            // chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            //     file: "metamask.js"
            // }, () => chrome.runtime.lastError);
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                code: "console.log('wow im in');"
            })
        } 

    }

});
```

so far my error i receive is

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access a chrome-extension:// URL of different extension
```

I am unable to run / execute the script because the url schema doesnt start with https / http. the url is starting with chrome-extension://

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you find a workaround for this?