# How to execute script targeting another extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

From within a Chrome extension, is there any way I can execute a script into another open extension? I just want to click a specific button whenever a different extension opens.

I tried using [chrome scripting APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/):

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
   target: { tabId: tab.id }, // tab id relative the other open extension
   function: injectIntoAnotherExtension
});

function injectIntoAnotherExtension() {
    document.getElementById('some-button').click();
}
```

At first I got the error:

```
Error: Cannot access a chrome-extension:// URL of different extension
```

After enabling the *Extensions on chrome:// URLs* flag (`chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls`), I now get:

```
Error: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://foo/bar/xyz.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

Here are my manifest permissions, which should allow all urls:

```
"host_permissions": [
   "<all-urls>"
]
```

I also tried with `*://*/*` or `chrome-extensions://*/*` but with no success.

Related questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679106/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-script-to-click-on-the-confirm-button-in-metamask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835203/how-to-execute-content-script-using-chrome-extension-to-a-url-starting-with-chr).

Any way around it? Or is there any other way to automatically click a button in another running extension?

Thanks!

Comment: Either use `chrome.debugger` API (can be used to automate access) or write a [devtools panel](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels) where you will use chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval while devtools is open on that extension's page and your panel is selected.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with chrome.debugger APIs!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), I got it working with:

```js
chrome.debugger.attach({
   tabId: tab.id
}, '1.0', function() {
   chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
      tabId: tab.id
   }, "Runtime.evaluate", { expression: 
      "document.getElementById('some-button').click();" 
   }, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
   });
});
```